# Trying to add scroll in menu dropdown

Tags: css, scroll, menu, dropdown

I got a problem with menu and adding scroll to it.

Ive added scroll(removed if afterwards) but then my other sub items are not showing, i tryed everything and I deciced to ask for help.

Ill try to explain a bit more:
I dont want horizontal scroll, I want vertical scroll and then when I hover over lets say "GELOVI" in shop I want that sub menu to pop out like it does without a scroll.

If you didn't understand me clearly please ask I will do my best to explain a bit more.

I am adding code sample here.

Thank you in advance.

```html
<ul class="sub-menu">
    <li id="nav-menu-item-16752" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom" data-cols="1"><a href="/shop/?orderby=date">Novosti</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-16663" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/akcija/">Akcije</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15809" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/sjajevi-i-baze/">Sjajevi i baze</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-18250" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/">Gelovi</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27918" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/clear-gelovi/">Clear gelovi</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27919" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/cover-gelovi/">Cover gelovi</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27917" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/babyboomer-gelovi/">Babyboomer gelovi</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27922" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/iconic-gel/">French gelovi</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27920" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gelovi/exclusive-gelovi/">Exclusive gelovi</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15786" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/babe-lak/">Babe lak</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15787" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/babe-lak/babe/">Babe</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15788" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/babe-lak/glitter-babe/">Glitter Babe</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15796" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/babe-lak/4in1-babe/">4in1 Babe</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15797" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/babe-lak/collection-babe/">Collection Babe</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-16838" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/primeri-i-tekucine/">Primeri i tekućine</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-25736" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/primeri-i-tekucine/acetoni-i-cleaneri/">Acetoni i Cleaneri</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-19601" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/primeri-i-tekucine/primeri-i-priprema-nokta/">Primeri i priprema nokta</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-25735" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/primeri-i-tekucine/ulja-za-kutikuli/">Ulja za kutikulu</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15805" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/raspe/">Rašpe</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15807" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/raspe/raspe1/">Rašpe</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15806" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/raspe/polir-blokovi/">Polir blokovi</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15808" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/sablone/">Šablone</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-27530" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/https-rich-nails-com-product-category-tipse-i-ljepilo/">Tipse i ljepilo</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-17082" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/kistovi/">Kistovi</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-21977" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/kistovi/gel/">Gel</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-21978" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/kistovi/nail-art/">Nail Art</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-21981" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/kistovi/ostalo-kistovi/">Ostalo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15798" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/metalni-pribor/">Metalni pribor</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-17127" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/elektricna-oprema/">Električna oprema</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27713" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/elektricna-oprema/elektricna-oprema-elektricna-oprema/">Električna oprema</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27716" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/elektricna-oprema/nastavci-comby-manikura/">Nastavci comby manikura</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27717" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/elektricna-oprema/nastavci-skidanje-gela/">Nastavci skidanje gela</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-17232" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/elektricna-oprema/dodatna-oprema-elektricna-oprema/">Dodatna oprema</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15791" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/dodatna-oprema/">Dodatna oprema</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-16959" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/dodatna-oprema/display/">Display</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27608" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/dodatna-oprema/cetkice-za-prasinu/">Četkice za prašinu</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-16958" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/dodatna-oprema/ostalo-dodatna-oprema/">Ostalo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15789" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/">Ukrasi</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-16522" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/aurora-prah/">Aurora prah</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15816" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/ukrasi-u-kolutu/">Ukrasi u kolutu</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-21754" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/cirkoni/">Cirkoni</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-27824" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/folije/">Folije</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15818" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/ukrasi/glitteri/">Glitteri</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-19653" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/merch/">MERCH</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15792" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/fashion/">Fashion</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15793" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/fashion/majice-i-hudice/">Majice i hudice</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15799" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/fashion/maskice/">Maskice</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15801" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/fashion/pregaca/">Pregača</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15800" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/fashion/ostalo/">Ostalo</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15802" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/gift-card/">Gift card</a></li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15795" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/trepavice/">Trepavice</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15813" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/trepavice/volumenske-i-klasicne/">Volumenske i klasične</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15812" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/trepavice/pincete/">Pincete</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15811" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/trepavice/ljepila/">Ljepila</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15810" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/trepavice/dodatna-oprema-trepavice/">Dodatna oprema</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-18737" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/">Zadnji artikli – 2mBeauty</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-18971" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/2mbeauty-gelovi-2mbeauty/">2mBeauty Gelovi</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20365" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/sjajevi-i-baze-2mbeauty/">Sjajevi i baze</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20370" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/tekucine-2mbeauty/">Tekućine 2mBeauty</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-18972" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/">Color Gel</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20032" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/carving/">Carving</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20033" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/effect-gel/">Effect gel</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20034" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/hc-magic-art-liquid/">HC Magic Art Liquid</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20035" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/plasteline/">Plasteline</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20036" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/spider/">Spider</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20037" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/stamping/">Stamping</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-21466" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/color-gel/termo/">Termo</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-18739" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/">Mini Me</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20025" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/all-in/">All in</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20026" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/cracking/">Cracking</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20027" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/elastic-base/">Elastic Base</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20028" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/galaxy/">Galaxy</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20029" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/holo/">Holo</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20030" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/intense/">Intense</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20031" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/metal/">Metal</a></li>
            <li id="nav-menu-item-20270" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/mini-me/magnet-effect-5d/">MAGNET EFFECT 5D</a></li>
        </ul>
</li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20345" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/acryl-gel/">Acryl Gel</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20373" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/dipgo/">Dip&amp;Go</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20392" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/raspe-2mbeauty/">Rašpe 2mBeauty</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-20393" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/2mbeauty/dodatna-oprema-2mbeauty/">Dodatna oprema</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
    <li id="nav-menu-item-15794" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat menu-item-has-children sub" data-cols="1"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/oklagije-za-maderoterapiju/">Oklagije za maderoterapiju</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15804" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/oklagije-za-maderoterapiju/oklagije-za-tijelo/">Oklagije za tijelo</a></li>
        <li id="nav-menu-item-15803" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-product_cat"><a href="https://rich-nails.com/product-category/oklagije-za-maderoterapiju/oklagije-za-lice/">Oklagije za lice</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Web: https://rich-nails.com/
Menu item: Shop

Please help me add scroll to it and make everything work good.

best regards,

Borna

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Comment: Alright, I'll do that now, I am sorry.

Comment: Your html is invalid. A ul cannot be a child of a ul

Comment: It is a sub-menu ( a really long one ) with another sub-menu in it. I copied that html part from website, it is working so it must be a valid onr. If you would check website that I posted I believe you would get it.

Comment: No, it is not valid. Run it through the W3C validator for that list of six errors before it gives up until you correct them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you want to do because you say "Ive added scroll" and I don't see scroll in this menu, but to add scroll to you're shop menu you can do this :

```
.sub-menu {
  max-height: 400px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: The problem is on sub sub menu items like the first one in shop menu "GELOVI". When we add that scroll people also have to scroll horizontaly, I am trying to avoid that.

So I need when someone hover over item in shop menu it pops out like normaly does without horizontal scroll, but vertical scroll has to stay.

I hope you understod me, if you didnt't Ill try to explain a bit more.

Thanks in advance!